# Filter branch/tag for Azure DevOps Pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

When you inside a pipeline and click the "Run Pipeline" button, the side bar shows where you select the branch to run followed by any custom parameters.

Right now, that "branch/tag" section shows all branches (feature, bugfix, release, etc.)

Is there a way to filter this list so we can remove the release branches from it?

[image: screenshot of section]

Comment: I'm afraid that this is not possible.

Comment: @KrzysztofMadej sad to see but I appreciate the response haha. Thank you

Comment: There are various ways you can stop a pipeline from running with the wrong branch; for example with a [check](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/approvals?view=azure-devops&tabs=check-pass) on the [Environment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/environments?view=azure-devops) specified in the pipeline, or on a [service connection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/service-endpoints?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) used by the pipeline

Answer (score 0):

Currently, Azure DevOps doesn't support removing certain branches from the filter. If you want such a feature, you could submit a feature request on:
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/report?space=21&entry=suggestion. Voting helps increase the priority of the issue by consolidating customer impact under one feedback.